# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in React app. But is disappears after refresh

Tags: laravel, reactjs, api, ecmascript-6, cors

I'm making a simple web application in React as front-end and Laravel as Back-end. I succeeded to get my data from the database but when I'm posting something in to the database I get the error message in my console:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque
>   response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to
>   fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Strangely when I submitted the form and refresh the page my data will show up.

my React Task Overview:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as TaskService from '../_services/Tasks.Service';
import { TaskForm } from '../forms/TaskForm.Component';

export class TaskOverview extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tasks: [],
        };
    }

    componentWillMount = () => {       
        TaskService.getAll().then(response => this.setState({ tasks: response }));
    }

    renderTasks = () => {
        let tasks   = this.state.tasks.map((task, i) => {
            return <li key={ i }>{ task.title }</li>
        });

        return tasks;
    }

    onFormSubmit = (data) => {
        TaskService.add(data);
    }

    render = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    { this.renderTasks() }
                </ul>
                <TaskForm onSubmit={ this.onFormSubmit } />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

my React service

```
export const getAll = () => {
    return fetch('http://projects/_own/ToDoLoo/api/public/task-overview').then((response) => {
        if ( response.status === 200 ) {
            return response.json();
        }
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
    })
}

export const add = (task) => {
    return fetch('http://projects/_own/ToDoLoo/api/public/task-add', { 
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(task),
        mode: 'cors', 
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        })
    }).then((response) => {
        if(response.statusText === 'OK') {
            return response.json();
        }
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
    })
}
```

My Routes

```
Route::get('/task-overview',    'TaskController@getTasks');
Route::post('/task-add',        'TaskController@addTask');
```

My Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Task;

class TaskController extends Controller
{
    public function getTasks () 
    {
        $tasks  = Task::all();
        return $tasks;
    }

    public function addTask (Request $request) 
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title'     => 'required|string',
            'body'      => 'required', 'string'
        ]);

        $task           = new Task;
        $task->title    = $request->title;
        $task->body     = $request->body;
        $task->user_id  = $request->user_id;
        $task->save();

        return back();
    }
}
```

i've also added a seperate Cors.php Middelware file with this function inside

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $request->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        return $response;
    }
```

and added the class it to my kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
```

I cant figure out how this error appears in my console when I'm posting a task and after I refresh the page the error will disappear and the task is added.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where did you add the `Cors` middleware? To which array in the kernel.php?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! i've added in the protected $middelware

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $request->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers','Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept, Authorization'));
```